# $.getScript - make variable stay global (so external file would see it) while keeping it inside the submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling on following issue: I have lot of validation before submit and I have put it into separate file so the page would load faster.  Now, on click of the submit button I want this validation file to load and validate everything.
The issue is that in order for external js file with validation to work I need the variables in that file to be seen and change each time I write something in input (I have an input, if I leave it empty and press submit I need validation to detect it (and it does) but if right after that I write something in input - I need the 'name' variable to change dynamically so that in loaded js file validation would work properly).
For that I need all the variables to be generated AFTER each time I press submit button BUT in order for dynamically loaded file (with validation which gets loaded if submit button is pressed) to access the needed variables (that detect whether or not the input is empty etc) I need the variables to be written out of scope - so that they are global and accessible to loaded js file. And if I declare vars right after `<script>` tag than they do not change dynamically each time I'd press submit button. (but at least loaded js file with validation sees them)

HTML:

```
<form action="videator-c.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='save_img'>
 <input type='text' class='name_video_inp' style="text-align: center;flex: auto;" maxlength="80" style='flex:auto' name='video_name' placeholder="*Name your video here" />
<input type='submit' value='Finish uploading video' name='submit-b'/>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var name = $.trim($(".name_video_inp").val());
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save_img').on('submit',function(){ var name = $.trim($(".name_video_inp").val());
         $.getScript("script/videator-b_validate.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log( textStatus );
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    console.log( 'error' );
});  
      return false;
    })
```

(I declared name variable both in scope and out of scope - if out of scope - it sees the variable but it is always empty even if I write something in input and press submit again and if in scope - name variable changes accordingly to the input value but it is not seen in external file. And I NEED BOTH: THE NAME VARIABLE TO BE SEEN IN EXTERNAL JS FILE AND THIS VAR GET CHANGED IF I WRITE SOMETHING IN INPUT AND THEN PRESS SUBMIT AGAIN.

and The EXTERNAL JS:

```
 console.log(name);
```

If I'd try to dynamically update name variable each time inout changes it would be declared in scope of a function and external js file wouldn't be able to see it:

```
$(".name_video_inp").change(function(){var name = $.trim($(".name_video_inp").val()); console.log(name);})
```

Here  is the working js that runs perfectly because I dont load file dynamically but it is already included there (but it is too long):

```
     $('#save_img').submit(function(){ 
        var lang_u = $('#lang_u option:selected').val();
        var lev_u = $('#lev_u option:selected').val();
           if(!$.trim($(".name_video_inp").val())){
          $('.hint').fadeIn(); 
          $('.hint').html('Please, name the video.')
          $('.hint').css('background','#fbf3b4');
          setTimeout(function() {$('.hint').fadeOut('fast');}, 3000);
          console.log('empty name');
          return false;}
        if($('.input_img').val() == '')
        { 
          $('.hint').fadeIn(); 
          $('.hint').html('Please, generate a thumbnail to the video by playing video at the desired position.')
          $('.hint').css('background','#8ced64');
          setTimeout(function() {$('.hint').fadeOut('fast');}, 3000);        
          return false;
        }      
        if (!$.trim($(".des").val())){
          $('.hint').fadeIn(); 
          $('.hint').html('Please, provide some description.')
          $('.hint').css('background','#ccfbb4');
          setTimeout(function() {$('.hint').fadeOut('fast');}, 3000);
          console.log('empty des');return false;}
        if(lang_u == 'Language' || lev_u == 'Level')
        {
          $('.hint').fadeIn(); 
          $('.hint').html('Please, select the Language and the Level.');
          setTimeout(function() {$('.hint').fadeOut('fast');}, 3000);   
          return false;   
        }
    })
```

So in general I struggle including external file on button pressed and getting it working - so that all the variables would 'work' the same as if it was inside the js file and not external.
The only solution I can see so far is to declare name variable each time after submit is pressed like this:

```
 $('#save_img').on('submit',function(){ var name = $.trim($(".name_video_inp").val());
```

And then somewhow how to make it global ?